# How to get coordinates of field CSV?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I read CSV file and display all fields in loop as:

```
for (int i = 0; csv.TryGetField<string>(i, out value); i++)
{
  // TODO
}
```

The `out value` gives me value of field.

But how can I get coordinates `x,y` of that fiels?

Structure file is:  `1 2 3 4 5
               6 7 8 9 10`

Comment: How is the stucture of your csv? What do you mean with x,y? line and column position?

Comment: I have is filled CSV file without column names. Each field has numeric value

Comment: What exactly  is `csv`

Comment: File with structure as matrix Excel file

Comment: okay, this doesn't help. Please edit your question and put more information into it. We don't see your code and structures!

Comment: Update question